# "undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass" when making a test for not logged in users in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading the book "Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Web Development with Rails 7th edition" and in chapter 10, we wrote a test to check if user is redirected to login page when not logged in as admin if they try to delete a user :

```
   test 'should redirect destroy when not logged in' do
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert_response :see_other
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

but I got this error on the console :

```
ERROR UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in (4.09s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:77:in `admin_user'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:60:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

and if I change this code :

```
def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user.admin?
    end
```

to :

```
def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user.present? && current_user.admin?
    end
```

as it was suggested in another post, then I get this error :

```
FAIL UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in (3.62s)
        Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/login> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/>.
        Expected "http://www.example.com/login" to be === "http://www.example.com/".
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:65:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have such code in the controller

```rb
redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user.admin?
```

If you try to call this method when current user is nil (non-authenticated user), `NoMethodError` will raise

To fix it use safe navigation syntax

```rb
redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user&.admin?
```

Next, you need to decide where you will redirect: to root page or login page. Depending on this corresponding tests will look like this

```rb
# controller
redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user&.admin?
# test
assert_redirected_to root_url

# controller
redirect_to(login_url, status: :see_other) unless current_user&.admin?
# test
assert_redirected_to login_url
```

Comment: cannot I redirect to two different pages depending on the test?

Comment: You can redirect to one path during one request. But if you have different redirects depending on conditions, you can repeat it in the tests